# Question about だの(?)

Tags: grammar

I hope it’s fine if I post a picture of a manga I’m reading here:

Chapter 6, Chainsaw man 1

[image: Chapter 6, Chainsaw man 1]

The boy lost his pet (it died) and it became his heart.

The phrase she says in the bottom there is tripping me up.

> 心{こころ}の中{なか}にいる**だの**なん**だの**は浅ましい{あさましい}慰{なぐさ}めじゃ！

I think it means:

«As for him living in there, its useless comfort»

I suspect it’s だの (and~) grammar but I know that なんだ is a different thing by itself. What is going on here?

Comment: Related?: [What does「〜も何も」mean in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62545/what-does-%E3%82%82%E4%BD%95%E3%82%82-mean-in-this-context)

Comment: Kind of related too, if you can work your brain to replace 心の中にいる with あー : [/what-does-まわりであーだこーだ-mean-in-this-sentence/](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18708/what-does-まわりであーだこーだ-mean-in-this-sentence/). It may be complicating but I hope you get the hang of it.

Comment: See this, too: ["だなんだと" meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49069/43676)

Comment: Thank you guys, Ive been biting at it for a while but I think I got it! If it’s ok to ask, the の keeps its function as ‘s right?

Comment: "the の keeps its function as ‘s right?" Oh no! I'm very sorry but you are wrong... Here's an example you could say to us: *"Related" だの "See this" だのうるさいんじゃ. Stop commenting and post a useful answer already!*

Comment: omg.. xD Thanks but why is the ああだこうだ using だ instead of だの? Or no significant reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25554/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82612/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Imabi](https://www.imabi.net/domodano.htm), なんだの is simply used when the speaker can only think of one item to include in the list that だの creates, in essence, making it 'Xs and whatever else'. The context thus lends itself to the following interpretation:

> Whether it remains there or not, that's little comfort!